# How can i automatically execute a script after automatic boot?

Tags: command-line, server, login

I've recently opened a VPS running Ubuntu server 13.10 x86 (**with no graphical desktop**) in order to run a game server. Since it's a VPS there's a risk that the node may crash when I'm not watching. This means I may want to have the server execute [this](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23114384/files/dedi.sh) script automatically when the server boots. How can I do that? Another problem is that it seems to require a username and password after boot.

Answer (score 1):

To execute a script at startup of Ubuntu

- Edit `/etc/rc.local` and add your commands
- The script must always end with exit 0

More information : [Executing a script at startup and shutdown](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/3348-ubuntu-executing-a-script-at-startup-and-shutdown)

Comment: aww, fixing it now :)

Comment: Thanks. I'm guessing that "exit 0" will terminate the the script, which is not what i want to happen with my keep-alive script. Is this really needed as a startup script or can i just use ctrl + c instead? Also I still need a way to get past the login screen :)

Comment: I cannot find that file, is that normal?

Comment: In new Ubuntu verions rc.local is not available anymore. Here there are two solutions: https://www.linuxbabe.com/linux-server/how-to-enable-etcrc-local-with-systemd